# how to perform click action on multiple text views from another layout Android

Tags: java, android

I have a text view in another layout and i am generating multiple text views using that reference. The problem is that I am unable to set Tags to those text views for click listeners.

This is my code for generating multiple text views

```
final CircularLayout circularLayout = findViewById(R.id.circular_layout);
        circularLayout.setCapacity(wordShuffled.length());

        for (int i = 0; i < wordShuffled.length(); i++) {
            text = (TextView)
                    LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.number_text_view, null);
            text.setText("" + tmp[i]);
            circularLayout.addView(text);
            text.setTag(String.valueOf(i));
           // m_ll.addView(text);

            tv.setTag(String.valueOf(i));

            m_ll.addView(text);
        }
```

This is the layout which contains that text view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textLay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I want to have click actions on each text view

Answer (score 0):

Create onClickListener out of for cycle, set it to generated textView. When you click textView, you should check tag and perform proper action.

```
final CircularLayout circularLayout = findViewById(R.id.circular_layout);
        circularLayout.setCapacity(wordShuffled.length());

OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
//handle on click event
}

        for (int i = 0; i < wordShuffled.length(); i++) {
...
textView.setTag(tag);
textView.setOnClickListener(listener);

...

}
```

Comment: for cycle is in method which runs only once. how can i place click listener into that method?

Comment: do you know something about that one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55467471/how-to-get-pattern-like-lock-password-apps-using-text-views-android

Comment: Seems it's custom view implementation:
- onTouch - save path points
- onDraw - draw on canvas path